# Color themes listed as available in Vim not changing upon :colo [themename] command

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, plugin-system, color

I am trying to install themes using V8+ Vim (8.2) on a Windows 10 OS. I first tried following the standard instructions listed on the Dracula theme site [here](https://draculatheme.com/vim). Unfortunately, the naming conventions for Unix based systems aren't the same as for Windows so I had to do a little research as to how to modify the instructions. So instead of `mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/themes/start` I created a directory in home `~/.vimfiles/pack/themes/start`. I then cloned the GitHub repository with `git clone https://github.com/dracula/vim.git dracula` inside of the start directory.

I then modified my vimrc file with `packadd! dracula`, `syntax enable`, and `colorscheme dracula`. I saved and restarted Vim. I confirmed that the colorscheme was set to dracula with the command `:colo` and double-checked that it was in the list of all color schemes with `:color [Space] [Ctrl+D]`. Everything looked like it should be working. Unfortunately I could see no evidence that the theme had changed from the default. I can switch to any of the other preinstalled themes such as "blue" or "desert". But I am unable to change to any of the ones I have attempted to add.

Any ideas where I am going wrong? I would have thought that I misnamed my `vimfiles` directory except that I would not have expected Vim to detect the theme and add it to the list. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Vimrc file**
[image: Screenshot of _vimrc file]
**What it ACTUALLY looks like in Vim**
[image: What it DOES look like]
**What it SHOULD look like in Vim**
[image: What is SHOULD look like]
**Scriptnames**
[image: scriptnames]
**Runtime Path**
[image: Runtime Path]

Comment: FYI I followed your steps (except using my path to my vim dir) and everything works for me. Did you try it with a stripped down vimrc? That is, nothing but the bare minimum config plus the above...?

Comment: I added a screenshot of my (now) minimal vimrc file

Comment: I did so and added screenshots. I'm not seeing anything that seems unusual although I admit I don't have expert eyes...

Comment: Looks like you might not have 256-color support in your Vim and Terminal... Take a look at questions such as this to see how to configure that: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/17464/18609

Comment: Wait a sec. I thought you said "I am unable to change to" the theme. You actually are and it just doesn't look right? That's something entirely different than I was thinking about. I agree that it may be you don't have  color support properly configured.

Comment: You could try `:set t_Co=256` or `set termguicolors`. That's the last shot for me.

Comment: I wasn't sure whether the theme was actually changing (with all that entails) or if Vim was merely being reporting falsely that it had. In any case :set termguicolors did the trick! Thanks for working through this.

Comment: Hey, maintainer of that theme here—you can set termguicolors if your term supports it, but the theme should fall back on 256 color sequences in a terminal w/o termguicolors. Now, it could be that there’s a mismatch between your terminal emulators palette and draculas, but I’m not sure. Please (a) use text instead of images for reporting scriptnames and runtimepath, (b) add an answer if you’ve solved the problem, and (c) consider opening an issue on our github if you’re still having trouble.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble For the fallback to work do you need `t_CO` set to 256?

Comment: @BLayer not necessarily—it may already be set, if TERM and the terminfo are configured right. I’m pretty sure we set both cterm and gui colors in the code so that it should “just work”—that said, clearly that didnt happen here

Comment: @BLayer I never set it manually. The terminfo database and TERM are supposed to coordinate to report this info, and vim (iirc) pulls from that info around startup to set it. This is why setting term can also set t_Co—and I do have to set term differently in tmux or alacritty. I find the sources saying “just force it to 256” dont have knowledge of cases where that actively breaks thing—like setting TERM to xterm-256color in environments where thats not appropriate. You *can* use it as an override, but with the right setup you often dont need to.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, that all jibes with my understanding of things. To the specific question of whether all that results in Vim putting a value in `t_Co` or not I'm getting "yes", then. Thanks!

Comment: IDK if this will work, but try reloading it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that finally worked for me (suggested in comments) was to add the following to my vimrc file:

```
set termguicolors
```

Apparently Vim was not using the full range of colors available to it.